# TypeScript generated JS files encoding

Tags: encoding, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS2015 and latest TypeScript (1.6.3). The generated JavaScript and map files are generated in Windows-1252 encoding. The source TypeScript  files are UTF-8 with BOM.
I do need the generated files to be UTF-8 with BOM as well in order to pass Windows Store certification.

Once I manually fix encoding of the generated files it's fine. But then I must include the generated files in source control and fix any newly added files.

There doesn't seem to be any settings to change the encoding.
Is this a bug in the compiler?

The project type is `jsproj`, which doesn't seem to support `tsconfig.json` according to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeScript is not fully supported in VS2015 in its current state (will update this answer if it changes in future).

In some project types you can use `tsconfig.json` and the compiler will then use the config. To do that you need to edit your project file and add element `TypeScriptModuleKind` with `amd` or `commonjs` specified to property group of the config file.

If your project type is for example `jsproj` there is not way to use the config file at the moment. Then you must must Gulp/Grunt or just simply call `tsc` manually fro command line. Or you can run a Powershell script to fix the encoding:

```
(Get-ChildItem ".\" -Recurse -Include ('*.js', '*.js.map')) | Foreach-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 7):

> Once I manually fix encoding of the generated files it's fine. But then I must include the generated files in source control and fix any newly added files.

Use the `emitBOM` and `charset` options in tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {

        //... other stuff

        "emitBOM": true,
        "charset": "utf8"
    },
    // ...
}
```

See schema : http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

Comment: Basarat, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't help. My project type is `jsproj` (which I now updated in the question) which doesn't seem to support `tsconfig.json` (according to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3124). Is there a way to either make the config work or to change the compiler settings without it? Also it is not just that the JS files are UTF-8 without BOM right now, they are encoded in Windows-1252 for some reason.

Comment: Manage the compile externally using something like grunt-ts : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#tsconfig

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But it's absurd that I have to do with the latest Visual Studio. Hopefully with a next update to VS2015 the support for TS will be better